# Sync 2 computer Emails

Tags: email

I have Gmail and have configured Windows Mail to work with it. I have done this on 2 computers. Once a week, I would like to sync the 2 Windows Mail accounts to look exactly alike, i.e., contacts, folders and messages. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IMAP, then your folders (labels) and messages will be synchronized automatically whenever Windows Mail downloads messages from Gmail.

If you're using Windows 8, you can link your local computer account to a Microsoft account on both computers, which will [keep select settings in sync](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs).

As for contacts, I believe you can export them to a file to import between computers (SkyDrive or some cloud-storage solution would be useful here). I'm not sure of a way to do this automatically though. I've never used the contacts functionality in any desktop mail. application.